How to interpret a phase kickback in Grover's algorithm
For the oracle of Grover's algorithm, there is an explanation that we use a phase-kick back as follows.
That is, we can tell if f(|x>) is 1 as it will change the output |x>.

My question is,

How can we be sure that the coefficient (-1)^f(x) is attached to |x>, not to the auxiliary bit (|y>)?

And why is this interpretation useful? I don't see any use of this auxiliary bit in implementing Grover's algorithm.


I'm looking forward to an answer to the above two questions.

Let's tackle your questions one by one.

How do we know that the phase change (-1)^f(x) is attached to |x>, not to the auxiliary bit (|y>)?


The reason we know that the phase change is attached to the input state |x>
(and not the auxiliary bit |y>) is due to the design of the quantum oracle
and the phase-kickback mechanism.
In Grover's algorithm, the oracle typically operates as a unitary
transformation U_f on the joint state |x>|y>, where |x> is the input state
(the state we want to search through), and |y> is the auxiliary bit. This
unitary transformation U_f is constructed such that it performs the
following operation:

U_f​ : ∣x>∣y> → ∣x>∣y ⊕ f(x)∣

Here, f(x) is a binary function. If f(x) = 1, the auxiliary bit |y> is
flipped (i.e., |y> ⊕ 1), and if f(x) = 0, it remains unchanged.
The critical observation here is what happens when we initialize |y> to a superposition state like |-> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0> - |1>). With this initialization, flipping the auxiliary bit results in a phase change instead of a flip. The following steps explain why this is the case:

When f(x) = 0, |y> remains |->.
When f(x) = 1, |y> flips to -|->.

The key here is that the operation results in adding a phase factor of (-1)^f(x) to the state |x>, while the auxiliary bit returns to its original superposition state.



Why is this interpretation useful? Why do we need the auxiliary bit in Grover's algorithm?


This interpretation and use of the auxiliary bit are useful because it allows us to encode the function f(x) into a phase change on |x>. This phase change is fundamental to Grover's algorithm, which relies on quantum interference to amplify the probability of the correct answer while suppressing incorrect ones.

The auxiliary bit provides a mechanism to "query" the function f(x) without permanently altering the state of |x>. Instead, it encodes the result in a phase, allowing Grover's algorithm to use quantum interference and amplitude amplification to find the correct answer. This phase-based operation is crucial for preserving the unitarity and reversibility of quantum operations, a cornerstone of quantum computation.

Thus, the auxiliary bit helps ensure Grover's oracle performs the desired transformation without altering the computational state permanently, while also facilitating phase-based logic that is at the heart of many quantum algorithms.


